# Casting a nullary data constructor between types

Tags: data-structures, haskell, data-types, type-casting

Suppose I have a parametrized data type with more than one nullary (constant) data constructor, such as:

```
data Check a = Valid | Invalid | Unsure a
```

Sometimes I want to manipulate the non-constant constructors with a function that keeps the nullary constants fixed, and I hope to do it like

```
instance Functor Check where
  fmap f (Unsure a) = Unsure (f a)
  fmap f c = c
```

This fails to typecheck because in the declaration `fmap f c = c`, if `f :: a -> b` then `c` needs to be of both types `Check a` and `Check b`. Of course I could just write it out fully into

```
  fmap f (Unsure a) = Unsure (f a)
  fmap f Valid = Valid
  fmap f Invalid = Invalid
```

which works but gets very unwieldy when there are many nullary constructors. Or, in some cases I could probably derive instances of `Show` and `Read` and use `read (show c)` to coerce `c` to the necessary type. But is there a more elegant way to approach this?

Comment: This is one of Haskell's weak spots. If you're feeling confident you could `unsafeCoerce` the difference away, but I wouldn't advise it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you could do is change the definition of your datatype to factour out the `Valid` / `Invalid` part like so:

```
data Status  = StatusValid | StatusInvalid
data Check a = Sure Status | Unsure a
```

You can then implement `Functor` without having to inspect the `Status`:

```
instance Functor Check where
  fmap f (Unsure a) = Unsure (f a)
  fmap _ (Sure s)   = Sure s
```

If you are willing to use the `PatternSynonyms` extension (just stick `{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}` at the top of your file), you can even recover `Valid` / `Invalid`:

```
pattern Valid   = Sure StatusValid
pattern Invalid = Sure StatusInvalid
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [DeriveFunctor](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html) extension and just write

```
data Check a = Valid | Invalid | Unsure a deriving Functor
```